# Firemonkey button fill style

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

I'm using Delphi XE3 and getting the hang of Styles. I want to change the colour of a button. I can change the text colour OK but can't find the 'fill' property in the style inspector, possibly as there is no TRectangle, just TSubimage and TRectAnimation for the button and all the help I can find refers to TRectangle. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XE3 the built in system styles (Win7, WIn8, Mac, MacHD) use bitmaps for the styles rather than building the styles from primitives. The style contains a png image which is divided into sections for each control and the various states of those controls. A TSubImage is used to select the appropriate section of the image. This may have child TRectAnimations to change the selected area for different states.

Your best way to modify such a style is probably to save the built in image (See http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2012/09/11/inspecting-the-default-platform-fmx-styles-in-xe3/ ), modify it, add it to your custom stylebook, and point the SubImage of your custom style to it.

Bear in mind, though, that you'll need to duplicate the above for all the platforms you are using so the style matches and load the appropriate one at run-time.

Comment: Thanks, looks like default colours then!! Not sure why buttons are treated like this when panels etc. can be assigned a colour.

Comment: While Mike is correct that bitmapping is used for XE3 bundled styles, it's still possible to build control styles from primitives. To build a button, use a TLayout with a TRectangle child, and a TText component childed to the rectangle. Set the text components StyleName property to "Text" (no quotes). From that, you have a valid stylelookup available to use with your buttons.

Comment: Agreed, @ScottPritchard, I was assuming the OP wanted to keep the original 'look-and-feel' but with different colours. Constructing a style from basics or an older style file might look jarringly different to the built in one.

Answer (score 0):

Both "buttonstyle" and "Cornerbuttonstyle" have a "background" that is a TRectangle and has a fill property.

I just got stuck on a similar problem yesterday trying to change the button colour at runtime. In my case I way trying to change the color property when the Kind was set to a gradient. I needed to change either the gradient colours or change the Kind to bkSolid.

Comment: I get buttonstyle with a background of TSubImage so no Fill.

Comment: The exact details of the style depend on the style you are using. System styles in XE3 use images, XE2 and others in XE3 use primitives. If you want to change a gradient fill, use a TGradientAnimation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Tokyo and I was using the aqua graphite style, but I wanted to also change the blue fill to another color.  After some research and fiddling around, and the comment by Martin was helpful, I was able to change the button color with the stylebook.

1. Right click the button, Edit custom style.
2. Find the button style and expand. In my scenario the style looks like this:

[image]

For the first selected Rectangle under my Background Rectangle, the moment I change the Kind to something else besides None, then you're able to do with it whatever you want. Give it a solid fill with Solid, or give it a gradient fill by changing the kind to Gradient.